# pyqt5でグラフ上をクリックしたときにその点での座標を調べたい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

pyqt5でmatplotlibを用いてグラフを描いた時に、グラフ上をクリックしたときにその点での座標を調べたいです。以下は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)



    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print("l")
            #print(event.xdata())
            #print(dir(event))

        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            pos=event.pos()
            print(pos.x())
            print(pos.y())
            #print("L")


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi) 


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        #canvas = MyCanvas(self)
        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが作成されます。
[image: 画像]
ここで、グラフ上で左クリックしたときにコンソール上に、クリック点でのグラフ上の座標が表示されるようにしたいです。しかし、どのようにすればよいのか分かりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

次のコードで動きました。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)

    def on_button_press(self,event):
        if event.button == 1: # MouseButton.LEFT:
            print('Left Button')
            print('xdata = ' + str(event.xdata))
            print('ydata = ' + str(event.ydata))
        elif event.button == 3: # MouseButton.RIGHT:
            print('Right Button')
    """    
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print("l")
            #print(event.xdata())
            #print(dir(event))

        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            pos=event.pos()
            print(pos.x())
            print(pos.y())
            #print("L")
    """


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi) 


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        #canvas = MyCanvas(self)
        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```